# Insert different UUID on each row of a large table by python

Tags: python, mysql, uuid

15

I have a table with ~80k rows with imported data. Table structure is as follows:

order_line_items

- id
- order_id
- product_id
- quantity
- price
- uuid

On import, the order_id, product_id, quantity, and price were imported, but the uuid field was left null.

Is there a way, using python's UUID() function, to add a uuid to each row of the table in bulk? I could use a script to cycle through each row and update it but if there is a python solution, that would be fastest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to add the default uuid for the table/model and and save value

```
from uuid import uuid4
from sqlalchemy import Column, String

class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    # add other column

records =[] # records in dict 
sess = session() # database session

# save all records in db
sess.bulk_insert_mappings(Table, records)
sess.commit()
```

Comment: tx bro for help

Answer (score 0):

A more Pythonic way in adding/modifying a value in a column is by using `map` method. You can find refer here for more details: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html.

Basically, what `map` is doing is map values of a column according to an function.

Your function must return a value for this to works, and you can take in the original value in the column as argument.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you can do this directly in MySQL using the [UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function.

```sql
UPDATE your_table_name SET uuid = UUID();
```

Comment: i know but i got order to do by python